# Can Web.config Transformation process impact on all solution's projects?

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to understand if what I have in my mind is a "good practice" and if so, how I can get it.

First of all let's say that we are using VS 2010 and the .Net 4.0.

In our solution we have one ASP.NET WEB Application and other Class Library projects, where some of them are referenced in the WEB Application project.

For the WEB Application we've implemented the "Web.config Transformation" since we manage the deploying on three different environments (Test, UAT, and Production).

The point is this, as I said we have projects referenced in the WEB App. and some of them access to the database, so the question is this: is there a chance to let the WEB.config transformation process to impact on those projects in terms of the connection string? Basically  before we deploy, once we select the environment (i.e Test), we'd like that choice will affect to the app.config files of the referenced projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reference library projects from a web project you configure them only with the web.config. You have to merge the config sections of the web and the library project to the web.config. After this you can use the config transformations to replace sections, connection strings, whatever of all parts of your project.

Here is a short description how to merge the config sections:

[web.config and app.config confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503247/web-config-and-app-config-confusion)

Comment: Thanks a million Dirk. We are going to test it.