# storing hierarchical application settings in web.config or app.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, web-config, app-config

I need to store my application config settings in a hierarchical format in web.config or app.config. Is this possible? or I have to store it in some XML file or database and use it instead? plain name value pair format isn't enough for me.

```
    <appSettings>
        <Report1>
          <add key="SourceFilePath" value="value1" />
          <add key="DestinationFolderPath" value="value2" />
        </Report1>
        <Report2>
          <add key="SourceFilePath" value="value1" />
          <add key="DestinationFolderPath" value="value2" />
        </Report2>
   </appSettings>
```

It is a web-based reporting application and I need to store the file paths for the source files, SSIS packages, FTP server details etc.

Update: If I choose the custom config section option, can I store the settings in a separate file to keep the main web.config file clean from app settings?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

Comment: Or http://www.google.com/search?q=ConfigurationSection

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/a/52252862/1767482

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add custom elements to `appSettings`.

The best way to achieve a custom format it to write your own `ConfigurationSettings` class and use that in configuration.

This will allow you to store data in a strongly typed way as well as have meaningful element and attribute names.

See [How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: thanks. looks like I need to write lot of code for it. it would be nice if there is an easier alternate solution

Comment: can I keep the application settings in a separate file if I choose this approach?

Comment: @RKP - Yes, this is something that comes for free (see the [`ConfigSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx) property). Just like you can have a separate file for the `connectionStrings` section.

Comment: I mean storing all the application settings in one file, not one file per section (report in my example). Is this possible?

Comment: @RPK - If your section is a _collection_ of these settings, then yes.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that as you suggest.

What you can do is to group by the key name the elements:

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="Report1:SourceFilePath" value="value1" />
      <add key="Report1:DestinationFolderPath" value="value2" />
      <add key="Report2:SourceFilePath" value="value1" />
      <add key="Report2:DestinationFolderPath" value="value2" />
</appSettings>
```

The best way though would be to define your own **ConfigurationSection.**

Here's some links about this:

- [How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)
- [Custom Configuration Sections in 3 Easy Steps](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx)
- [Creating Custom Configuration Sections In ASP.NET](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Creating_Custom_Configuration_Sections_In_ASPNET.aspx)

Comment: can I keep the application settings in a separate file if I choose this approach?

Comment: Which approach ? Special key names or configuration sections ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't store xml elements they way you suggested in appsettings.
If you need a hierarchy as you mentioned try one of the following approaches

1. Store whole xml elements in appsettings an parse the xml

   ```
   <appSettings>
     <add key="Report1" value="<Report1 SourceFilePath=""value1"" DestinationFolderPath=""value2"" />" />
     <add key="Report2" value="<Report2 SourceFilePath=""value1"" DestinationFolderPath=""value2"" />" />
   </appSettings>
   ```
2. Store the xml in config section (see answers above)
3. Use the [DslConfig](https://github.com/johannes-brunner/DslConfig) project.
    Add it with NuGet and look add the AppSpike for examples.
   In your case you could create a class ReportConfig and use this class as configuration class.
    Example:

   ```
   public class Report {
     string SourceFilePath { get; set; }
     string DesinationFolderPath { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Create a config File entry in Variables.var

```
   import ReportClassNamespace from ReportClassAssembly

   Var["Report1"] = Report(SourceFilePath:"value1",DesinationFolderPath:"value2")
   Var["Report2"] = Report(SourceFilePath:"value1",DesinationFolderPath:"value2")
```

1. Try the [NConfig](https://github.com/Yegoroff/NConfig) project

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I know is to create your own Settings class and serialize/desiarilze it in order to read/write your app. settings.

Also you can use Admin. page of your website to save all settings into it.

May be in your case is better to use a database to keep all settings there as well.